# IIS cannot serve images due to impersonation?

Tags: iis, iis-8.5, 500-error, impersonation

We have a brand new Windows2012R2 server. We have installed the IIS features on it (including static content).

Then we have deployed a web site on it (using copy).

When we surf to the web site, HTML, CSS and JavaScript is served up just fine.

However, requests for `png` and `ico` requests gets a response HTTP status 500, substatus 0, win32-status 1346.

[The 1346 status seems to indicate an impersonation problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asgoyal/2012/08/25/one-thing-you-must-do-when-getting-http-500-0-1346-error/).

But why are we getting it for just the images?

And more importantly, how can we fix this without turning on impersonation?

EDIT: actually, it did not help to add `IIS_IUSRS` to `Impersonate a client after authentication`.

Comment: Have you already tried this ms suggestion? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asgoyal/2012/08/25/one-thing-you-must-do-when-getting-http-500-0-1346-error/

Comment: Are the images local to the IIS server?

Comment: @GregAskew yes.

Comment: @arana yes, it did not help

Comment: The problem disappeared when I rebooted the server. Don't you just love windows?
Anyway, I'm leaving the question here, cause I would still like to know what was wrong, because this is not the last web server that I will deploy this site on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same weird error and the most frustrating thing in the world is a reboot worked.
These are all the steps i used, maybe they help some one even though they do not supply root cause.

We set "Impersonate client after authentication" permissions via GPO in.

Computer config >> Windows settings>> Security Settings >> Local Policies >> User Rights Assignment.

I added the user we have for our site with this issue to that group, it is the user for the website and app pool.

updated GPO ensured new settings showed user permissions on the local server, but still no luck.

Then we rebooted the server and it all worked. So i dunno if these changes require more then a GPO update to resolve the issue.

Comment: Actually, after setting the "Impersonate client after authentication" permission, you only have to iisreset. No reboot necessary.